# Define a scalable flexible layout in WinRT XAML using Viewbox and a background image for many different resolutions

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

My goal is to create a XAML page that has a kind of "Splash Page" or "Start Page" that is 70% the width of the screen (on the left), with the other 30% (on the right) being the first portion of the content which is the next panel in a scroll viewer. This scroll view can indefinitely scroll and present various content, but regardless of the resolution of the screen, we should still see that 70/30 split.

I am trying to accomplish this with a Viewbox, several grids, and image brush for the background.

The problem is that on large resolutions, like 1600xFOO the left had (70%) panel takes up the whole screen. On a Surface Tablet, or smaller resolutions like 1366x768, it sizes it correctly.

This is the XAML I am using - high level:

[image: ViewBox_XAML_Sample]

And here is a quick comp of how I would like this XAML to behave, regardless of resolution:

[image: XAML_Mockup]

On large screens the left hand panel ends up taking up the whole screen.

Here are some resources about scaling and multiple resolutions in WinRT and Windows Store apps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465349.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066871/winrt-scale-to-fit-issues

One thing I would like to AVOID doing (this is a no brainer to most XAML pro's I imagine) is using any REAL widths, or detecting the screen resolution during runtime and doing sizing dynamically:

http://programmerpayback.com/2013/08/31/detecting-screen-resolution-in-windows-8-and-windows-phone-apps/

One thing I am not opposed to but would like to avoid is doing the Width={Binding MyParentGrid ActualWidth} hack, which seems to work but I am trying to use pure Viewbox/Grid scaling.

I think the key to my problem is defining the stretch/alignments better in the parent panels, or by using some other kind of xaml trickery.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanisms you're hoping to use to solve this (star sizing and Viewbox) are dependent on the size of their parent container to auto-calculate sizes. In a normal window this makes it easy to do a percentage split because a Grid at the root knows what size its immediate parent window is. In this case you've inserted a ScrollViewer between those two parts of the layout, so the Grid no longer knows about the visible size, only about the ScrollViewer's ExtentWidth. The size you care more about for sizing that first column is the ViewportWidth (roughly equivalent to the window width).

Probably the most straightforward way to handle this is to set the size from code-behind based on the screen size. You'll also need to reset on the window's SizeChanged event for window splitting and screen rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but the 70/30 split can be easily done like this:

```
  <Grid >
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <ListView Grid.Column="1"/>
   </Grid>
```